# How to override the default "from" email address in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I have set up SMTP for gmail with laravel's built-in mail functionality. Everything works fine. I see mails passing through smoothly. However, I have to set the "from" mail id in the laravel's `mail.php` file where I keep my SMTP settings. How can I override this setting? If I try to do `$message->from(mailId@some_other_domain_than_one_with_SMTP_hosted_mail_ids)` then it won't go thorugh. Also, if I remove the default mail Id from `mail.php` and try to do `$message->from(mailId@mail_id_with_SMTP_hosted_email_ids)` then it will pass through. 
So my question is,
1. How do I override the default `from_mail_id`

because I am working on a messaging system where `from_id` has to be different. Any idea?

Comment: `$message->from("some@email.com");` should work fine to override the default. I use it all the time... I don't think this is a problem with Laravel, but your smtp provider?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Probably the problem is with SMTP provider